# Google Maps user-editable polygon with fixed number of points in Android?

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps, google-maps-markers, polygon

I am working on Google Map polygon marker, I have predefined lat/long array, and need to set polygon area, It is working fine for me, but when I drag the marker polygon line doesn't change, it should have to be change as I drag the marker.

Here is my problem, I'll put a picture to illustrate it easier.

[image: This is my polygon]

here is the code :

```
    myMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
            updateMarkerLocation(marker);
            drawPolygon(coordinates);

        }

        private void updateMarkerLocation(Marker marker) {

            LatLng latLng = (LatLng) marker.getTag();
            int position = coordinates.indexOf(latLng);
            if (position >= 0) {
                coordinates.set(position, marker.getPosition());
                marker.setTag(marker.getPosition());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {

        }
    });
}

private void drawPolygon(List<LatLng> coordinates) {

    if (polygon != null) {
        polygon.remove();
    }

    PolygonOptions polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();
    polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.GREEN);
    polygonOptions.strokeColor(Color.GREEN);
    polygonOptions.strokeWidth(3);
    polygonOptions.addAll(coordinates);
    polygon = myMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);

}
```

[image: after dragging marker]

like above image my marker move but not make polygon.

**coordinates contain polygon coordinates from sqlite**

Comment: Please add the full error stack trace.

Comment: In `updateMarkerLocation`, if `markerlist` doesn't contain `latLng` then `position` will be -1. The next line  `markerlist.set(position, marker.getPosition());` will then throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Maybe add a check for `position >= 0`, or if this shouldn't happen trace back to determine why.

Comment: @SirRaffleBuffle ` if (position >= 0) {
                    markerlist.set(position, marker.getPosition());
                    marker.setTag(marker.getPosition());` i update my code like this now that error gone but when i drag my point it drag perfectly but i am unable to make polygon

Comment: @BlackCoder have you find any answer ?

Comment: @shivanipatil No

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the `Marker` tag to store the last displayed coordinate (`LatLng`) of the polygon point. The coordinates to be displayed are stored in `coordinates` yes?

If so then I'm guessing your code should be:

```
private void updateMarkerLocation(Marker marker) {
  LatLng latLng = (LatLng) marker.getTag();
  int position = coordinates.indexOf(latLng);
  if (position >= 0) {
    coordinates.set(position, marker.getPosition());
    marker.setTag(marker.getPosition());
  }
}
```

Comment: you are right. and i replace markerlist with coordinates, but no luck, getting same error

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using the tools you have a little inefficiently. My recommendation would be to store an array of markers, and use markerTag to store the index of your point, so in drawPolygon

```
for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++) {
   markers[i].setTag(i); //Associate a marker with a point
}
```

Then, when you move the marker, you would replace the co-ordinate at that point like so:

```
points[marker.getTag().toInt()] = marker.getTag().getPosition();
```

Sorry this is so vague. I use kotlin, so I've probably gotten some of the syntax wrong, too.